# Get the video tag of youtube embed videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to change the playback rate of an embed youtube video, is there any way to get the video tag?

I know that the video is held in an iframe, could a chrome extension be used to bypass the security?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API creates a public JavaScript object that allows you to control the YouTube video. By default the object is called *player*.

The only problem is if the developer assigned it to another object.

I guess what you need is not to bypass the iframe, you just need to detect the name of that object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the HTML5 YouTube player:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]
```